# How to return backbone collection in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json, backbone.js

I'm fetching a backbone collection using .NET MVC and am having trouble populating the collection properly. The data I need is returned but is inserted incorrectly in the collection.

What follows is all the details related to fetching the collection.

***My model***

```
_.namespace('My.Model');

My.Model.UserAssistance = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        Id : '',
        Title: '',
        Content: '',
        Width: 175,
        Popover: true,
        ArrowPosition: "top-left",
        ArrowDimensions: {
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        }
    }

});
```

***My collection***

```
_.namespace('My.Collection');

My.Collection.UserAssistance = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: function () {
        return '/user-assistance'
    },

    model: My.Model.UserAssistance
});
```

***Fetching the collection***

```
this.collection = new My.Collection.UserAssistance();

        var $elements = $('[data-help-id]'),
            values = $elements.map(function () {
                return $(this).data('help-id');
            }).get();

        this.collection.fetch({
            data: {
                HelpIds : values
            },
            // required for correct serialization of the array
            traditional: true
        });
```

***Controller method***

```
        [Authorize]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult Default(List<string> HelpIds)
        {
            List<UserAssistanceViewModel> models = new List<UserAssistanceViewModel>();

            foreach (string helpId in HelpIds)
            {
                UserAssistanceViewModel model = new UserAssistanceViewModel();

                model.Content = (Resources.UserAssistance.Content.GetResourceById(helpId));
                model.Title = (Resources.UserAssistance.Titles.GetResourceById(helpId));
                model.Id = helpId;
                models.Add(model);
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                models : models
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

When the collection is returned the collection is updated as follows:

*userAssistance.collection.toJSON()*

```
[
Object
ArrowDimensions: Object
ArrowPosition: "top-left"
Content: ""
Id: ""
Popover: true
Title: ""
Width: 175
models: Array[6]
  0: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  3: Object
  4: Object
  5: Object
  length: 6
  __proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong but I don't know how else to format the data to be returned. You can see that it's actually adding a sub level in the form of an array of object called "models".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return the actual models list in the controller action:

```
    [Authorize]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult Default(List<string> HelpIds)
    {
        List<UserAssistanceViewModel> models = new List<UserAssistanceViewModel>();

        foreach (string helpId in HelpIds)
        {
            UserAssistanceViewModel model = new UserAssistanceViewModel();

            model.Content = (Resources.UserAssistance.Content.GetResourceById(helpId));
            model.Title = (Resources.UserAssistance.Titles.GetResourceById(helpId));
            model.Id = helpId;
            models.Add(model);
        }

        return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

If you absolutely must keep the `models` property, override your [collection's parse method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) to return the `models` property from the response:

```
My.Collection.UserAssistance = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: function () {
        return '/user-assistance'
    },

    model: My.Model.UserAssistance,

    parse: function (resp, options) {
        return resp.models;
    }
});
```